# Change order matrix-array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

Good night,

I need to convert the result of a operation and I don´t how:

```
C = np.matmul(A, B)
print(C)
```

I get:

[[1 3 22 6]

[5 14 5 3]

[44 31 24 33]]

But I need:

[[1 5 44 3]

[14 31 22 5]

[24 6 3 33]]

How i can convert the first result to get the second one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transpose the matrix, reshape to a 12-element vector (or 1x12 matrix), and then reshape to the final form.

Answer (score 1):

`np.matmul` multiples backwards
from how you would imagine: try `C = np.matmul(B, A)`. It's harder given we don't have the matrices `A` or `B` !